# How does lambdas and reference method work in this example?

Tags: java, oop, lambda, java-8

I have a doubt about the functioning of the following code since the Car class does not implement the Rideable interface, and I don't know how it is possible ?

I'm using two ways to do it, one is lambda and the other with reference method.

```
interface Rideable {
    Car getCar(String name);
}

class Car {
    private String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //both lines are valid for compilation
        Rideable rider = Car::new; 
        //Rideable rider = c -> new Car(c); 

        Car vehicle = rider.getCar("My Car");
        System.out.println(vehicle.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you think you're using the `Rideable` interface in a way that should require `Car` to implement it?

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks, I had to find the analogy with the functional interfaces and the predicate class to understand it

Comment: Note that your `Rideable` interface is structurally identical to `Function<String, Car>`, and it's very common to use `Car::new` where a `Function` is requested.

Comment: May I suggest that the people (the riders) implement a Rider interface, and the cars (things able to be ridden) implement a Rideable interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Car::new` is not 'a new car'.

`new Cake()` is like: "make a cake; once you've made it, make that the value of the expression `new Cake()`.

`Cake::new` is nothing like a cake. It's not a cake whatsoever, and its value implements none of the interfaces cake do. After all, `Cake::new` is a *cake recipe*. It is a thing capable of **making cakes**, and that has nothing to do with cakes. You can eat a cake. You can't eat a recipe, or an oven. Or a baker (well, I guess you can, but let's not get weird with this. Certainly eating a baker is going to taste nothing like a cake).

In java, 'recipes' like `Cake::new` are 'untyped' - instead, the compiler looks at the context; the stuff *around* this expression. That's why this:

```
    Object o = Cake::new;
```

is not going to compile: From context, there's no hints whatsoever as to what you're trying to do here.

The context needs to tell the compiler exactly what sort of recipe is required, and then the compiler will check if the recipe you've written will fit these needs. If yeah, great, then that's what you get. If not, you get a compiler error.

So, back to your code:

a `Rideable` describes a recipe: Any recipe that takes as input a name, and turns that into a `Car`, can be deemed a 'Rideable'. Given that this is an interface that defines precisely one method, it is a so-called FunctionalInterface, and those are special: You can use lambda syntax or method reference syntax to create a new rideable on the fly. The compiler will 'fit' the lambda/reference expression to act as a new instance of Rideable.

Turns out, `Car::new` fits the bill! There is a constructor that takes a string, and constructors effectively 'return' a Car, which matches that one defined method that Rideable has. Thus, the compiler has determined from the context what you want, that it fits, and goes ahead and does it. Therefore, this:

```
Rideable r = Car::new;
```

is just syntax sugar for this:

```
Rideable r = name -> new Car(name);
```

which is basically syntax sugar* for this:

```
Rideable r = new Rideable() {
    public Car getCar(String name) {
        return new Car(name);
    }
}
```

which is syntax sugar for this:

```
    public class YourCustomRideable implements Rideable {
        @Override public Car getCar(String name) {
            return new Car(name);
        }
    }

    Rideable r = new YourCustomRideable();
```

*) There are slight, basically irrelevant differences between the two; the compiler produces slightly different byte code. There are ways to observe this difference, such as asking for the identity hashcode of the rider, but, don't. You're not supposed to treat these things as having a relevant identity, the whole point of your 'instance' of Rideable is that you intend to invoke `getCar` on it **and nothing else**. As long as you do that, these 4 lines of code are all entirely equivalent.

Comment: thanks, it's very clear now, I had to find the analogy with the functional interfaces and the predicate class to understand it too, but now it's very clear

Answer (score 2):

```
Car::new
```

has a meaning which depends on the context in which it is used.

In this case, it is the same as:

```
Rideable rider = name -> new Car(name);
```

A `Rideable` is just something which takes a `String` and gives you back a `Car`. This doesn't require `Car` to implement `Rideable`: you're using its constructor, which takes a `String`, and gives you back a `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

That lambda is equivalent to `new CarRideable()` if there were a class defined somewhere like this:

```
class CarRideable implements Rideable {
  public Car getCar(String name) {
    return new Car(name);
  }
}
```

`Car::new` just says to use the `Car` constructor to implement the one and only method in `Rideable`, which it can.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 used the concept of interface for introducing another concept which is called  `lambda expression`.

First of all you should know about `FunctionalInterface`, Functional interface is an interface with only one abstract method in it  here you have  defined `Ridable interface` which has only `getCar` method in it.

Second you should know `lambda` can be assigned to functional interface and the type of the lambda will be specified by the abstract method of the functional interface. So here instead of your code we could have:

`Rideable rider = (String name) ->  new Car(name);`

here `(String name) -> new Car(name)`  is a lamba expression, you can see the signature of lambda is the same as abstract method in `Ridable Functional interface`.  But here the right hand side of lambda do nothing but calling a method (which here is a cunstroctor) so isn't it better to just refer to that method instead of creating a lambda like this:

`Rideable rider = Car::new;`